# $\ln k$ where $k>2$

Tags: calculus

Let $k>2$, is a natural number, and also it's true $\ln k=\int_{1}^{k}\frac{dt}{t}=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dt}{t}+\int_{2}^{3}\frac{dt}{t}...\int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dt}{t}$. Then, is $\ln k-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n}<\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n^2-n}$?For $lnk$ we can use the formula, from before.  Then for the right side, we can use partial fractions? and seperate $n^2,n$. So it's true.

Next questions, is $\lim_{k \to \infty}[\ln k-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n}]$ exists? So this is calculating for a sequence and $lnk$. But $\frac{1}{n}$ is always diverge, when $k=\infty$, so I think no, it's not exists.

Comment: As $k \rightarrow \infty, \ln k \rightarrow \infty$ as well so you get $\infty - \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$\begin{array}\\
\ln k-\sum_{n=2}^{k}\dfrac{1}{n}
&\lt \sum_{n=2}^{k}\dfrac{1}{n^2-n}\\
&= \sum_{n=2}^{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=1-\dfrac1{k}\\
&\lt 1\\
\end{array}
$

so the difference is bounded.

By being a little more careful,
you can show that
the limit of the difference exists.
This is called the
Euler-Mascheroni constant,
denoted by 1-$\gamma$,
with a value of about
1-0.57721.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant
for more information.